# jQuery.cycle1 and jQuery.cycle2 conflicts in two plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on two plugins. In first plugin i used jQuery.cycle.1 and its work in first plugin perfectly. In second plugin i used jQuery.cycle.2 and its also work in second plugin perfectly, but when i install these two plugin in one theme they Conflict.

I also use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

but nothing happen, please help me what can i do.

i include jQuery cycle1:

```
http://localhost/plugin_test/wp-content/plugins/logo-slider/jquery.cycle.all.min.js
```

And this is my jQuery cycle2

```
http://192.168.2.2/plugin_test/wp-content/plugins/wp-catalogue-pro/includes/js/jquery.cycle2.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put cycle1 and cycle2 files in same project see this link [jQuery.cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/)

You must remove jQuery.cycle1 file